# Why will this function not work?

Tags: php

I have the following function that I know should return TRUE but it will not.

```
function myFunc($str,$array)
{
  foreach($array as $k=>$v) 
  {
    if(strtolower($v) == strtolower($str)) 
    { 
      return TRUE; 
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

This function is used inside a class in an if statement `if($this->myFunc($something, $array)){`

No matter what I do, it will not return true even though I echo some text above the return TRUE; and that is displayed. Any help for something I am missing, that would be great.

Sorry for not posting the codes.
My array prints the following

```
Array
(
[0] => -1
[1] => Platinum
[2] => 169
)
```

and

```
$something = '-1';
```

I am trying to return true if -1 exists. The problem I don't think is if the value is in the array. The issue I have is to why it will not return as true, it will echo a value but it will not return anything. I tried using in_array and the function still did not return as true, which is why I tried this method. Could this be an issue with my PHP version?
I used strtolower because this function will be reused throughout the page to search for other values.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the contents of $str and $array. :)

Comment: I agree stick a var_dump($str); var_dump($array) at the start of the function.

Comment: have you debugged using print_r on your array?

Comment: Show the *exact* code that invokes the function.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the values for $str and $array?

Comment: It doesn't return TRUE, because $v is not the same as $str.  PS. If you are just looking to see if a variable is in an array, use `in_array` or `array_search`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the function you've given here.  Either this is not the exact code you are using, it really _shouldn't_ return true, or there's a problem with your usage of it.  Please tell us how you're using it.

Comment: @Rocket: those functions are good, but he needs a case-insensitive search.

Comment: I've updated with the array and needle I am trying to search for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see no nothing wrong with your function, but as alternative you could try:

```
return in_array(strtolower($str), array_map("strtolower", $array));
```

Comment: +1, Essentially the same function, but uses two loops instead.

Answer (score 1):

`This function is used inside a class in an if statement if($this->myFunc($something, $array))`
Does modifying the if statement to the following change the answer?

`if(myFunc($something, $array))`

Just a thought as perhaps `$this` isn't being evaluated at the correct time.

Comment: If I remove $this, it throws an error that the function is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in_array` or `strcmp` to accomplish this.

> Return Values
>
> Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2;
>
> > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal